# Header and paragraph hiding behind image

Tags: jquery, css

## Info

Wie ben ik? Welke herstellingen doe ik?

```
#navigation {
height: 810px;
width: 884px;
}

#navigation h1 {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
font-size: 18px;
}

#navigation p {
padding-left: 20px;
}

#home-block, #info-block, #prices-block, #contact-block {
position: relative;
    float: left; 
    width: 440px; 
    height: 300px; 
    background: #e7e8d9;
}

#home-block, #prices-block {
border-right: 4px solid #fff;
}

#home-block, #info-block {
border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.a {
position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
 }

.b {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
 }
```

I wanted to create a fading image with jQuery. This worked, but now my header and paragraph are hiding behind the image. You can test this on [link text](http://ashwinmertes.be)

I want my header and paragraph underneath the picture, just like the other 3 sections. How do I arrange this?
Thank you!

Comment: Ik ben niemand en ik herstel niets (I am nobody and I won't fix anything).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution is

```
#home-block > a {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
}
```

but this will break if your image's size is changed. (Though it doesn't look like you'll change that frequently.)

Answer (score 0):

If you give your `<h1>` a `margin-top` of about 200px it should work. The problem is that when you make the images absolutely positioned, they're no longer contributing to the running content inside that containing `<div>`; it's as if they're not there at all.

Comment: Ok thanks, that worked. But do I need to absolutely position my images or is there another solution? Thanks!

Comment: Well given that you've got *two* images that need to reside in the same place, you don't have much choice I don't think.